# Angularjs - ng-options within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple problem, but don't know how to solve it. The values of partsignalType are not getting populated in my dropdown list.
    This is my js code:

```
var testModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope) {                      


        $scope.participants = [{
              partSignalId: '13077223000',              
              partName: 'abc',
              partSignalType: ['H323','SIP']             
            }]       


}     

And my html code:

<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <th md-column>Select</th>
          <th md-column><span>Name</span></th>
          <th md-column md-numeric><span>Participant Aliase</span></th>
          <th md-column><span>Protocol</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr md-row md-select="dessert"  md-select-id="name" md-auto-select ng-   repeat="participant in participants | filter: search">
                      <td md-cell><input type="checkbox" ng-model="participant.selected"></td>
                      <td md-cell>{{participant.partName}}</td>
                      <td md-cell>{{participant.partSignalId}}</td>
                      <td md-cell>
                        <select ng-model="participant.partSignalType" ng-options="partSignalType" required >
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                        </select> 
                      </td>
                    </tr>   
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `select` to this

```
<tr id="formattyperow" ng-repeat="participant in participants | filter: search">
        <td class="label-cell">* Participant type :</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="partici" ng-options="partici for partici in participant.partSignalType">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            Value : {{partici}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/0gf0gL0o/4/)**